# Try/except in Python - out of range/eof

Tags: python, try-except

I'm a beginner in Python. I just now encountered try/except in Python. I'm having a hard time to this things without having an Eof problem or out range when I use except.

I want to loop over a list of tuples to check how many students have passed and how many have failed. Unfortunately not all students have the pass/will clause.

How do I solve this without getting a runtime error?

```py
try:
    students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'),
                    ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'), ('Archie', 71),
                    ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]
    passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

    for tup in students:
        if tup[2] == "Will pass":
                passing['Will pass'] += 1
        elif tup[2] == "Will not pass":
            passing["Will not pass"] += 1
try:
    students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'),
                    ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'), ('Archie', 71),
                    ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]
    passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

    for tup in students:
        if tup[2] == "Will pass":
                passing['Will pass'] += 1
        elif tup[2] == "Will not pass":
            passing["Will not pass"] += 1

except IndexError:
    for tup in students:
        print(tup[2])




    # ...
```

Comment: Every `try` block must have a following `except` block

Comment: Some of your tuples only contain 2 elements, so that will cause an error to be thrown.  You could just test the length before doing an invalid index, but if you'd rather catch it with an except, then just add an `except` clause to your `try` statement.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: @DeepSpace , iv'e edited the code to include except. even now i'm still receiving runtime error although iv'e inserted the code as well in the except part . i thought it's going to skip this kind  of error when adding "except IndexError:".

Comment: You need to delete one of the try statements.

Comment: inside the except block, you will get *another* IndexError because you're trying to print tup[2]. You could just do `print(tup)` and it will run without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you want to practice try/except. In that case you should remember:

- Every try block must have an except block or it will throw error
- You need to put only that code chunk in try block where error is likely to happen.

So you can use following modification of your code:

```
students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'),
                ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'), ('Archie', 71),
                ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]
passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

for tup in students:
    try:
        passing[tup[2]] += 1
    except:
        print('No status for student: ', tup[0])
print(passing)
```

This produce following output:

```
No status for student:  Martha
No status for student:  Ashley
No status for student:  Archie
{'Will pass': 3, 'Will not pass': 2}
```

Comment: oh now i  understand. the except allows me to follow the errors .thanks for the help.

Comment: My pleasure! Kindly consider accepting the answer if it resolved the error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) - lots of examples in there, see also [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=indexerror#IndexError).

Here's how not to crash when accessing an invalid index.

```py
students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'),
            ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'),
            ('Archie', 71), ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]
passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

for tup in students:
    try:
        if tup[2] == "Will pass":
            passing['Will pass'] += 1
        elif tup[2] == "Will not pass":
            passing["Will not pass"] += 1
    except IndexError:
        # handle error here
        pass
```

---

Another solution without try/except - just check the `len()` of the tuple:

```py
students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'),
            ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'),
            ('Archie', 71), ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]
counter = [0, 0, 0]

for student in students:
    if len(student) > 2 and student[2] == "Will pass":
        counter[0] += 1
    elif len(student) > 2 and student[2] == "Will not pass":
        counter[1] += 1
    else:
        counter[2] += 1

print("Passing:", counter[0], "Not passing:", counter[1], "Missing attribute:", counter[2])
```

---

And here's another solution using `filter`, `map` and `reduce` just for fun:

```py
from functools import reduce

students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'),
            ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'),
            ('Archie', 71), ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]

p, n = reduce(
    lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]),
    map(
        lambda x: (1,0) if x[2] == 'Will pass' else (0,1),
        filter(
            lambda x: len(x) > 2,
            students
        )
    ),
    (0,0)
)

print("Passing:", p, "Not passing:", n)
```

Comment: i want to practice try/except so that's why  i rather not check the length of the tuple. but thanks for the reply .

Comment: @RonGoldstein added another section with try/except